# Logcat says “The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.” on my 2nd alert dialog

Tags: android, view

As I said in the title, I have 2 alert dialogs showing on user interaction. I have menu that has 4 options: Settings, Credits, Promocode and Exit one, but when I click on Promocode, I got an error mentioned in the question. This is my code:

```
switch ((int) mMergeAdapter.getItemId(position)) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Browser.this,
                                SettingsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Browser.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Credits");
                        builder.setMessage("Code\n\nTraabefi\n\nDesign\n\nSamuel 'Samael' Chmura");
                        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.holo_dark_action_info);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                        TextView txt = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                        txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Browser.this);
                        alert.setTitle("Enter your promocode.");
                        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
                        alert.setView(input);
                        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        if (input.getText().toString()=="abcd"){
                                 isPremium = true;
                        }
                        else {
                                 isPremium = false;
                        }}});
                        alert.show();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        finish();
                }
```

Comment: Post your logcat. Which line causes the error? This error occurs when you add a child to a parent that is already added to it.

Comment: I know what it means, but the error causes the kibe 384 which is "alert.show();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines causing the error are:

```
 final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
 alert.setView(input);
```

`android.R.id.edit` is part of the fragment, and, as the error states, this view has already a parent. To fix you problem, you can define your xml, use an inflater to retrieve the view object and call setView, providing this one as parameter.

Edit:

create a xml file, in the res/layout folder. Call it `my_edit_text.xml`, with the content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and replace

```
final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
alert.setView(input);
```

with

```
 final View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.my_edit_text, null); 
 alert.setView(view);
 final EditText input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.myid);
```

Comment: what do you mean by connect

Comment: Can you please post a code ? I am just the beginner

Answer (score 1):

As the guy blackbelt said the error is in the fact that you are trying to use something that does belong to the fragment. Instead of android.R.id.edit use your own.
Take a look here: 
[Custom Dialog](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/dialog/android-custom-dialog-example/)